# MySQL/JDBC: How to "atomically" remove rows and then add one new row

Tags: mysql, jdbc, atomic

I have the following scenario:

```
1. DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id = ?;    // Prepared statement.
2. INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(?, ?, ..., ?); // Also a prepared statement.
```

## Question 1

Suppose two clients (let's call them `A` and `B`) execute the two operations above. *Is that possible that all four operations are executed as follows?*

- `A` executes operation 1.
- `B` executes operation 1.
- `A` executes operation 2.
- `B` executes operation 2.

(This will introduce 2 new rows when I want only 1.)

## Question 2

If the answer to question 1 is yes, how can I disable "interleaving" described above. Or in other words, how can I make sure that `A` performs ***both*** operations 1 and 2 first, and ***then*** `B` performs both the operations. Also, how to accomplish this with JDBC?

Comment: Did you read about [transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)?

Comment: @YCF_L So I first disable autocommit, do my updates and call an explicit commit, is that correct?

Comment: yes you have to put the both operation in the same transaction you can find many good articles in google but i think the one i share can help you

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe is precisely the reason why most database management systems support the notion of [Transaction management](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

> A transaction is a set of one or more statements that is executed as a unit, so either all of the statements are executed, or none of the statements is executed.

The term "atomic" is used to refer to actions that occur "as a unit" in the above quote.

A further refinement to the implementation of transactions is the notion of [Transaction isolation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#transactions_data_integrity). It describes how multiple processes should behave when they are operating on a database where transactions are in effect. In your specific case,

*"how can I make sure that A performs both operations 1 and 2 first, and then B performs both the operations"*

it sounds like you want to use a transaction isolation level of `TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE` which (as the name implies) ensures that multiple transactions are managed in a way that is effectively "serial", e.g., forcing process_B to wait until process_A's transaction is complete.

Comment: This is part of what makes [Multi-Version Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (MVCC) so powerful.